# table name as report builder parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I've got an ugly database structure - tables are named for fiscal years, as in `GL_2011`, `GL_2012`, etc.

I need to allow the user to tell me which fiscal year they want to get data from, then construct the table name, and then execute the query.

I've had some success with building a string assigned to `@SQL_QUERY` and `EXEC`uting it.. But MS Report Builder seems to get lost in the process and often doesn't populate my fields in the dataset.  Other times I get erratic errors where I am trying to piece the query together.

Simple Example:

```
DECLARE @SQL_QUERY VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL_QUERY = 'SELECT ITEM_1, ITEM_2 FROM ' + 'GL_' + CAST(@FISCAL_YEAR_PARM AS VARCHAR(4));

EXEC(@SQL_QUERY)
```

Comment: If you have to use dsql adding a PRINT @SQL_QUERY line helps a ton when debugging in SSMS.

Comment: Have you considered a view instead of dynamic SQL? Also, can you give an example of the errors?

Comment: No errors per se - Report Builder allows me to run it (results correct in the spreadsheet window) but when I click OK I see that the dataset does not have the fields from the query.  Clicking on 'refresh fields' has no effect.  And as for views - they are discouraged here.

Comment: Today I saw a strange thing happen.  Report was working but I made a very small edit and previewed it - it worked properly.  Then I opened the query to check I had things set up correctly (no changes); clicked OK to return to the design level - and it blanked the dataset fields and the report would no longer run. Clearly there is some instability when it comes to dynamic sql.

Comment: Hum.  I've found that if I "refresh" like a Skinner-monkey (actually only 2 or 3 times) it will often populate the fields. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion. In order to have SSRS recognize the columns returned by the query, develop a stored procedure that populates a temp table and returns the rows of the temp table.  Pass in the fiscal year to determine which db to query (or do it dynamically like you have) to populate the temp table.  If you do that, then SSRS knows the columns that will be returned with each call, and will make those available in Builder.